# Map through a json file to get an array, with just the values I need

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a relatively large json file, and would like to map through this and get only the names ​​that have id 1. I am using React typescipt. Could someone help me?

Comment: Did you try `const A = data.filter(el => el.id === '1').map(el => el.name)`?

Answer (score 1):

Why map and not filter?:

```
var data = [ 
    {   
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Carl",
    
    },  
    {   
    "id": "1",
        "name": "Carlaa",
    },  
    {   
      "id": "2",
        "name": "tim",
    },  
    {   
           "id": "5",
        "name": "daniel",
    },];

console.log(data.filter((d) => d.id == "1"));
```

second bit:

```
f = (id) => data.filter((x) => x.id === id).map((x) => x.name )
console.log(f("1"));
```

Comment: But if i Am dooint that export const Function = (id: string) => {
   
    data.filter((x) => x.id ===i d).map((x) => x.name
  
    ) and then in the app.js 
onsole.log(Function(1)) I am getting undefined
 

}

Comment: you either need to remove the curly braces or add the return keyword.  Return is only implied in the absence of the braces.  In addition, I wouldn't override "Function", that's a core class, and you should be passing in a string, as your IDs are string formatted.

Comment: GOD BLES YOU <<<<3333

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call:

```js
data.filter(x => x.id === '1').map(x => x.name)
```

This returns:

```js
[ "Carl", "Carlaa" ]
```

Comment: @DanielRg You could define the type like `interface User { id: string; name: string; }`

Comment: But if i Am dooint that export const Function = (id: string) => {
   
    data.filter((x) => x.id ===i d).map((x) => x.name
  
    ) and then in the app.js 
onsole.log(Function(1)) I am getting undefined
 

}

Comment: @DanielRg If you put `{}` around the arrow function body, you need to `return` explicitly. Simply remove the `{}` around.